# I want to download the linkedin profile picture when a new user login with linkedin

Tags: image, download, profile

```
IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id","first-name", "last-name", 
"email-address", "headline", "siteStandardProfileRequest", "picture-url", 
"industry").result(displayProfiles);
```

Comment: I suggest to show more, what you tried, what happened, what problems you found.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge You can use 2 approaches.

1. Use ***Jsoup*** to get the Image as a bytes stream and save it to a given directory using FileOutputStream.(But you need to input URL of each and every user)  [Refer Jsoup Tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-tutorial)
2. Use ***Selenium*** to Automate the Linkedin Logging process and download the image  [Selenium Official page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: thanx for the reply i definitely try this in the mean time i come up with a solution as well.